# ubuntu 17.10 snapd.service takes too long at boot

Tags: boot, snap

I regularly run systemd-analyze to keep a check on boot-times. I recently noticed that the snapd service is taking way too much time than it used to do before. Kindly suggest a solution to reduce it.

P.S. I would also be grateful for suggestions to reduce the boot times of other services mentioned below too.

The following is the output of systemd-analyze critical-chain

```
graphical.target @24.395s
└─multi-user.target @24.392s
  └─snapd.service @13.856s +10.534s
    └─basic.target @13.193s
      └─sockets.target @13.187s
        └─snapd.socket @13.149s +28ms
          └─sysinit.target @13.039s
            └─apparmor.service @11.445s +1.589s
              └─local-fs.target @11.425s
                └─run-user-1000.mount @23.575s
                  └─local-fs-pre.target @3.494s
                    └─systemd-remount-fs.service @3.380s +74ms
                      └─system.slice @2.104s
                        └─-.slice @2.030s
```

The following is the output of systemd-analyze --blame

```
          10.534s snapd.service
          7.678s dev-sda6.device
          7.608s ModemManager.service
          6.233s accounts-daemon.service
          6.085s udisks2.service
          4.706s grub-common.service
          4.325s apport.service
          3.809s systemd-logind.service
          3.642s networking.service
          3.590s alsa-restore.service
          3.536s pppd-dns.service
          3.531s bluetooth.service
          3.523s thermald.service
          3.483s avahi-daemon.service
          3.364s NetworkManager.service
          3.355s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          3.004s speech-dispatcher.service
          2.906s rsyslog.service
          2.636s gpu-manager.service
          1.994s fwupd.service
          1.951s polkit.service
          1.706s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-EE66\x2d6196.service
          1.589s apparmor.service
          1.232s mnt-7C5CC02A5CBFDCD8.mount
          1.068s keyboard-setup.service
```

Comment: Bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1667882 (snapd taking enormous amount of time to boot)

Comment: Can you look at the output from ` journalctl -xeu snapd` to see what steps of snapd running is eating time. Also, perhaps ` systemctl edit snapd` and add the following two lines ```[Service]
Environment=SNAPD_DEBUG=1 SNAPD_DEBUG_HTTP=7``` - then restart and check the journal again. See what's consuming time.